# C# - Disable Dynamic Keyword

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, late-binding, dynamic-keyword, late-bound-evaluation

Is there any way to disable the use of the "dynamic" keyword in .net 4?

I thought the Code Analysis feature of VS2010 might have a rule to fail the build if the dynamic keyword is used but I couldn't fine one.

Comment: Why?  There is nothing evil about dynamic.

Comment: Are you trying to enforce this as a rule amongst a team of developers? In that case, I suggest two tools: grep and a cricket bat.

Comment: Cricket bat? Come on, cattle prods are much more effective. http://www.enasco.com/product/C13638N

Comment: Wow!  There are a lot of smart a$$ developers around.  I'm attempting to appease management by disabling dynamic so I can start using VS2010 and .net4.  I don't think dynamic is evil, quite the opposite when its used appropriately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's part of the C# 4.0 language, so no not really.

You can use [FXCop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429476.aspx) to look for it though and fail the build if it encounters it.

Style cop might work instead:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/sourceanalysis

Here is a link talking about the same issue and how style cop might be the answer.  There is also a post about how to get FX cop to potentially look for the dynamic keyword, although it's not perfect.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vstscode/thread/8ce407ba-bdf7-422b-bbcd-ca4701c3a76f

Comment: turns out FxCop can find dynamic class-level fields, method params, and method returns via the DynamicAttribute but can not find local variables inside methods b/c they are converted to objects without any attribute.

Comment: @cheif7 I did some more looking and style cop might be the way to go.  I posted a link to some posts about the same problem.

Comment: Thats my post.  StyleCop looks like it will work well.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

The dynamic keyword is not evil, but using it could be.

It leads to code errors that you can only find during runtime.
This should be avoided at all costs.
Runtime errors are bad. Compile time errors are good.

You could use something like the following to set your own standards.
http://joel.fjorden.se/static.php?page=CodeStyleEnforcer

Comment: Reflection does that too. Nobody ever bans reflection though, its just sort of understood that it is a very specific tool for a very specific job, and sometimes the perf hit and the lack of compile time errors are worth it, cause there is literally no other way to do certain kinds of things. Ditto with dynamic. Using it everywhere by default is moronic, but at the same time, there are certain types of things where the tradeoff is worth it.

Comment: Reading files from disk that might be invalid, or assuming registry or configuration files exist, etc, is also "only found at runtime". :-)

Answer (score 2):

Target .net 1.0? :-)

Or do code reviews.

(Or, to be less facetious, it should be pretty easy to write a custom FxCop or CA rule to disallow use of dynamic)

Wouldn't you just kill for a C++ macro right now? :-)

Answer (score 2):

Remove the reference to `Microsoft.CSharp.dll`, and I think maybe all uses of `dynamic` will fail to compile.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand what this irrational fear of the dynamic keyword is for. There was this type of hysteria over anonymous variables and the var keyword for .NET 3.5 except that was just idiotic since those are legitimate statically defined types.

The dynamic keyword serves a highly specialized purpose, I don't see why any person would have the desire to use it without understanding why. However stopping that from occurring could be solved with 1 team meeting explaining some of the new features of .NET 4 including the dynamic keyword. I assume you're more of a senior or the senior lead of the team; it should be quite easy to tell your team if they ever feel they NEED to use the dynamic keyword to come see you FIRST.

This was exactly the instructions I gave to my team as I find it unlikely we will ever use the dynamic keyword because we don't write COM interop activity. And past that I will defer any type of dynamic proxy use to an established library like Linfu or Castle and leave up the implementation of dynamic proxies to them to use or not use the dynamic keyword.